# When I make 2 turtles collide, Python freezes and crashes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
import os
import math

ms = turtle.Screen()
ms.bgcolor("grey")
ms.title("ok")

ground = turtle.Turtle()
ground.speed(0)
ground.color("black")
ground.penup()
ground.setposition(-500, -500)
ground.shape("square")
ground.shapesize(20, 200)

player = turtle.Turtle()
player.shape("square")
player.color("blue")
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
player.setposition(-450, -280)

playerspeed = 15

prop = turtle.Turtle()
prop.speed(0)
prop.shape("square")
prop.penup()
prop.color("red")
prop.setposition(-200, -50)

def move_left():
    x = player.xcor()
    x-= playerspeed
    if x <-460:
        x = - 460
    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor()
    x+= playerspeed
    if x >460:
        x =  460
    player.setx(x)

def move_down():
    y = player.ycor()
    y-= playerspeed
    if y <-290:
        y = - 290
    player.sety(y)

def move_up():
    y = player.ycor()
    y+= playerspeed
    if y >290:
        y =  290
    player.sety(y)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(move_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(move_right, "Right")
turtle.onkey(move_up, "Up")
turtle.onkey(move_down, "Down")

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(t1.xcor() - t2.xcor(), 2) + math.pow(t1.ycor() - t2.ycor(), 2))
    if distance < 10:
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:
    if isCollision(player, prop):
        player.setposition(100, 100)
```

If I change the distance to `> 10`
it works but not as I want it to.
I want it to change the position of the `player` when `prop` and `player` are 10 pixels or less away from each other.
I've tried most things I know about, but I am still new to Python, or any programming language.

But I don't know what would cause it to freeze and crash -- any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue I see with your code is `while True:` which shouldn't be used in an event-based environment.  By creating a tight loop, you can keep events (key pressed, cursor movements, window closing) from being processed.

Below is a rework of your code using a timer event instead of `while True:`.  I've also parameterized it as every turtle user sees a different size default window based on the dimensions of their screen.  So you either need to use `setup()` to force a fixed size window or have your code adust to the window size.  Now it adjusts to the window size.  I've also made `prop` move to a random location upon collision, just to make the game more fun for me to play.  And I've tossed your distance code in favor of turtle's own implementation:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop
from random import randint

PLAYER_SPEED = 15
GROUND_HEIGHT = 100
PROXIMITY = 10
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def move_left():
    x = player.xcor() - PLAYER_SPEED

    if x < CURSOR_SIZE - width/2:
        x = CURSOR_SIZE - width/2

    player.setx(x)

def move_right():
    x = player.xcor() + PLAYER_SPEED

    if x > width/2 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        x = width/2 - CURSOR_SIZE

    player.setx(x)

def move_down():
    y = player.ycor() - PLAYER_SPEED

    if y < CURSOR_SIZE/2 + GROUND_HEIGHT - height/2:
        y = CURSOR_SIZE/2 + GROUND_HEIGHT - height/2

    player.sety(y)

def move_up():
    y = player.ycor() + PLAYER_SPEED

    if y > height/2 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        y = height/2 - CURSOR_SIZE

    player.sety(y)

def isCollision(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < PROXIMITY

def random_position():
    x = randint(CURSOR_SIZE - width//2, width//2 - CURSOR_SIZE)
    y = randint(CURSOR_SIZE + GROUND_HEIGHT - height//2, height//2 - CURSOR_SIZE)

    return x, y

def check():
    if isCollision(player, prop):
        prop.setposition(random_position())

    ms.ontimer(check, 100)

ms = Screen()
ms.bgcolor('grey')
ms.title("ok")

width, height = ms.window_width(), ms.window_height()

ground = Turtle('square')
ground.shapesize(GROUND_HEIGHT / CURSOR_SIZE, width / CURSOR_SIZE)
ground.speed('fastest')
ground.penup()
ground.sety(GROUND_HEIGHT/2 - height/2)

player = Turtle('square')
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('blue')
player.penup()
player.setposition(CURSOR_SIZE/2 - width/2, GROUND_HEIGHT + CURSOR_SIZE/2 - height/2)

prop = Turtle('square')
prop.speed('fastest')
prop.color('red')
prop.penup()
prop.setposition(random_position())

ms.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
ms.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
ms.onkey(move_up, 'Up')
ms.onkey(move_down, 'Down')
ms.listen()

check()

mainloop()
```